# How I can download file from web in Cake?

Tags: cakebuild

I'd like to download protobuf archive from github releases (https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protoc-2.6.1-win32.zip) during my Cake build.

I don't found the answer on [Cake DSL reference page](http://cakebuild.net/dsl).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTTP / web operations are found under
http://cakebuild.net/dsl/http-operations

[DownloadFile(string, ​FilePath)​](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.net/af7d8a3b/12f58205) is probably what your looking for.

Example usage:

```
DownloadFile(
    "https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protoc-2.6.1-win32.zip",
    "./protoc-2.6.1-win32.zip"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** [Answer from Matias Karlsson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537411/how-i-can-download-file-from-web-in-cake#answer-37537587) is correct! Use it!

One of other Cake usage, if you can't find some functionality:

Cake is just .NET-based script. You can use [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ez801hhe.aspx) method.

For example:

```
var buildDir = new DirectoryPath("./target").MakeAbsolute(Context.Environment);
var protocLink = "https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protoc-2.6.1-win32.zip";
var protocArchive = buildDir.CombineWithFilePath("protoc-2.6.1-win32.zip");

Task("DownloadProtobuf")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadFile(protocLink, protocArchive.FullPath);
        }
    });
```